# Get input value on Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pretty new to reactjs. I am trying to print the value 0f input. I tried doing this.

```
 var ProductListing = React.createClass({
        onIdChange : function (a){
            //var test=0;
            console.log(a)

        },
        render : function(){
            return (

                    <div>
                        <div className="field">
                            <label htmlFor="">Id :</label>
                            <input type="number" id="txtId"  onChange={this.onIdChange.bind(this)}/>
                        </div>
```

This doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: what are you getting in console.?

Comment: Proxy {dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: ReactDOMComponent, _dispatchInstances: ReactDOMComponent, nativeEvent: Event, type: "change"…}[[Handler]]: Object[[Target]]: SyntheticEvent[[IsRevoked]]: false

Comment: `a.target.value` might work.  However, you are not setting `value` so you might need a `ref`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems correct. As your method is already getting called, just try  this code.

```
onIdChange : function (e){
          this.setState({inputValue:e.target.value})
            console.log(e.target.value)
    },
```

And add value attribute like this,

```
<input type="number" id="txtId" value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.onIdChange.bind(this)}/>
```